# Changing length of Shortest_Line for CAD-like slope pattern using QGIS

Tags: qgis, slope, geometry-generator

I haven't found a tool/plugin that could do this, but I am almost there. Here is what I want to do:

[image]

I want to create a slope like the ones from CAD programs, but I don't have and don't need a DEM. It's just for the visualization of the slope.

What I did so far:

1. Create 2 line layers for the upper slope (blue) and the lower slope (green)
2. The Tool "Points along geometry" is creating 2 point layers. 1 layer has points every 6 meters, the other one has points every 6 meters with an offset of 3.
3. With
   ***shortest_line($geometry, aggregate('testline', 'collect', $geometry))***

on both point layers, I am able to create lines from one point to the lower slope line, so it looks like a connection of both slope lines.

**I need every second line to be half as long. How can I do that?**

Can I change the length of the "shortest_line"?

I tried to multiply with 0.5 and other things, but nothing worked so far.

Is there an alternative function?

Should I try something with "make_line", some points and angles?

I am not really good when it comes to coding in QGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this expression to generate a line with a length of 50% using the following expression - replace `*0.5` at the 7th last line with any percentage you like:

```
with_variable (
    'varinter',
    intersection (
            extend (
                shortest_line(
                    $geometry, 
                    aggregate (
                        'testline', 
                        'collect', 
                        $geometry
                    )
                ),
                1,
                1
            ),
            aggregate(
                'testline', 
                'collect', 
                $geometry
            )
        ),

make_line (
    $geometry, 
    project (
        $geometry, 
        length (
    make_line (
        $geometry, 
        @varinter
    )   
)
*0.5,
        azimuth (
            $geometry, 
            @varinter
        )
    )
))
```

What it does: it takes the lines you created (dotted black line), finds the intersection with the lower slope and creates a point where the lines cross (white dots). You have to extend the lines a bit, as sometimes no intersection is created.

You than can measure the angle (azimuth) between the points on the upper (blue dots) and the lower slope line (white dots) - basically its the angle of the line you already created - but, as can't directly measure the angle of the line, you have to do it using two points.

Than, you can create a new point (red dots), using `project` to project the point on the upper slope (`$geometry`) for a certain distance (the length of the whole black dotted line *0.5) in a certain azimuth: the angle calculated before. Finally, connect the point on the upper slope (again `$geometry`, blue dots) with this newly created point (red dots) and you get the red lines.

[image]